# How come an array inside an instanciated object returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

```
function test() {
    var test_array = [];
}

var arrayList = new Array();
arrayList[0] = new test();
arrayList[0].test_array[0] = "test";
```

([try it out](http://jsfiddle.net/5t62z/))

I'm trying to create an array, initialize an object as a member of that array, and then assign a text value to an array inside that object. However the array inside the object gives

```
TypeError: arrayList[0].test_array is undefined
```

when I try to assign a string to the inner array. I'm still pretty new to javascript so any tips to best practice in this case would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The test_array variable is only accessible within test().  You have to expose it with "this"

Comment: See possible duplicate [Javascript: Do I need to put this.var for every variable in an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418669/javascript-do-i-need-to-put-this-var-for-every-variable-in-an-object) for the difference between variables and properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Statement `var test_array = [];` creates a local variable which will not be visible outside the scope it is defined within. What you need here is the variable defined as the property of object instance. Use `this` reference inside your `test` function:

```
function test() {
    this.test_array = [];
}
```

For more information on scopes in JavaScript read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzt2dkta%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

Comment: When I make this change the I get SyntaxError: missing variable name

http://jsfiddle.net/5t62z/4/

Comment: @WilliamMartin: There's no syntax error in this answer. Read and type carefully and double check your work. You're doing `var this.test_array = [];`, which isn't valid.

Comment: @WilliamMartin strange, I've modified your fiddle as I've described and printed the value of `arrayList[0].test_array[0]` via `console.log(arrayList[0].test_array[0])` - it worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

`var` declarations within a constructor don't actually modify the instance. They're just locally-scoped within the constructor function itself.

To define a property of the instance, you have to modify `this`:

```
function test() {
    this.test_array = [];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/5t62z/3/

Your function was not returning anything. If you notice my update, I now will return an object with the `test_array` property.

```
function test() {
    return {
        test_array: []
    };
}
```

Comment: *"Your function was not returning anything..."* Yes it does. It returns a new object because it was invoked using `new`. http://jsfiddle.net/5t62z/5/